# Does Blender Support ARM Texture maps

Tags: modeling, texturing, shaders

Hi I downloaded a model from a site and the there's a ARM texture and I have no idea how to put it on the model I tried ctrl, shift, t and it recognized the normal map and the regular texture but it didn't import the ARM texture I found out its a combination of Ambient Occlusion, Roughness and Metallic and its separated by RGB. As seen below.
but I would like to know how to use it into blenders shading tab

ARM is short for Ambient Occlusion, Roughness and Metallic. The ARM Texture Map combines the three textures into a single texture maps separate color channels Red, Green and Blue.

Red – Ambient Occlusion

Green – Roughness

Blue – Metallic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the '**Separate Color**' node, which was called Separate RGB a few updates back can help you solve your problems.

[image]

From there you can plug in the **Separate Color** node outputs into there respective slots into a principal BSDF or any other network you have made up.

**Edit**

This is one way you can combine your AO with your base/albedo map. Plug the red channel into the value slot and your base colour texture into the color slot of a **Hue Saturation Value** node. The output of the **Hue Saturation Value** node then goes to the Base Color of your Principled BSDF.
[image]

You can also use the mix node for similar results.
[image]

Comment: Hi so how do I add the Ambient occlusion to the principal BSDF?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the answer to include this question. Let me know if this is what you are after.